# python etree parse xml with html entities ( keep html formatting )

Tags: python, html, xml, elementtree

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:metadata="http://xmlns.escenic.com/2010/atom-metadata">
 <content type="application/vnd.vizrt.payload+xml">
    <vdf:payload xmlns:vdf="http://www.vizrt.com/types">
      <vdf:field name="body">
        <vdf:value>

          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>I saluti dal Sud partono con <strong>Elsa Albonico</strong>, storica  "golosit&#xE0;", con i pi&#xF9; piccoli "fare le conte".</p>
            <p>I saluti dal Nord la <a href="http://www.proticino.ch/sezioni-in-svizzera/basilea/">Pro Ticino di Basilea</a> con un particolarit&#xE0; frammenti&#xA0;&#xA0; </p>
            <p><a href="https://www.rts.ch/">RTS</a> "Kiosque &#xE0; Musiques" con <strong>Jean-Marc Richard</strong>. <br/>A fare da<em> fil&#xA0;rouge</em> al nostro </p>
            <p>
              <a href="http://internal.publishing.production.rsi.ch/webservice/escenic/content/8762014" id="_360b1131-e6a5-49b6-995e-a624c888617a">Le foto del gioco, Finestra popolare 26.02.2017</a>
            </p>
          </div>

        </vdf:value>
      </vdf:field>
    </vdf:payload>
  </content>
 </entry>
```

the "body" field is the HTML I have to copy to another file as html (so no replace or other tricks allowed )

I'm using python and eTree.

Is there a way to do this ?

I already tried to use the tail instead of the text, but I'm losing the formatting 
of the HTML which is a big problem.

please help.

thanks

cp

Comment: can you add, what you tried ?

Comment: sorry, i don't have the examples handy anymore. Also i cannot now replicate the problem because when i get the xml from the webservice, and i parse it with ElementTree i now get some annoying html: namespaces for the html div which now looks like :

Comment: this : <html:div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> and don't know how to remove them.  any idea ?

Comment: Clad, if you have new question, ask seperate, no one, sees your comments in this post without me.

Comment: When you get xml from webservice, you can store it in file before parsing, that way you will have data to reproduce this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I just find a workaround and don't need to work on this anymore. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very ugly solution, but works! As home work, make it better!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:metadata="http://xmlns.escenic.com/2010/atom-metadata">
 <content type="application/vnd.vizrt.payload+xml">
    <vdf:payload xmlns:vdf="http://www.vizrt.com/types">
      <vdf:field name="body">
        <vdf:value>

          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>I saluti dal Sud partono con <strong>Elsa Albonico</strong>, storica  "golosit&#xE0;", con i pi&#xF9; piccoli "fare le conte".</p>
            <p>I saluti dal Nord la <a href="http://www.proticino.ch/sezioni-in-svizzera/basilea/">Pro Ticino di Basilea</a> con un particolarit&#xE0; frammenti&#xA0;&#xA0; </p>
            <p><a href="https://www.rts.ch/">RTS</a> "Kiosque &#xE0; Musiques" con <strong>Jean-Marc Richard</strong>. <br/>A fare da<em> fil&#xA0;rouge</em> al nostro </p>
            <p>
              <a href="http://internal.publishing.production.rsi.ch/webservice/escenic/content/8762014" id="_360b1131-e6a5-49b6-995e-a624c888617a">Le foto del gioco, Finestra popolare 26.02.2017</a>
            </p>
          </div>

        </vdf:value>
      </vdf:field>
    </vdf:payload>
  </content>
 </entry>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
div = tree.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0]

with open('./result.html', 'w') as html:
    html.writelines([i for i in div.itertext()])
```

Comment: hi, sorry but all i get is  ElementTree instance has no attribute 'getchildren'
did you manage to get it to work ?

Comment: I just ran that code before post the answer! I tested on Python 3.6 and 2.7

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I just find a workaround and don't need to work on this anymore. thanks anyways.